# How Base conditions in haskell works?

Tags: haskell

I'm starting to do my firsts steps in Haskell. I have worked with recursion problems in the past using Python.
Just for practice purposes, I'm trying to write a function witch reverse a list:

```
reverse2 lst =  if length lst == 1
                then lst !! 0
                else (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
```

I get the error:

```
SimpleFunctions.hs:9:22: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
    • In the expression: (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
      In the expression:
        if length lst == 1 then
            lst !! 0
        else
            (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
      In an equation for ‘reverse2’:
          reverse2 lst
            = if length lst == 1 then
                  lst !! 0
              else
                  (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
    • Relevant bindings include
        lst :: [a] (bound at SimpleFunctions.hs:7:10)
        reverse2 :: [a] -> [a] (bound at SimpleFunctions.hs:7:1)
  |
9 |                 else (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

But if I change by

```
reverse2 lst =  if null lst
                then []
                else (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
```

It works!

Why the first option is not correct?

Comment: Beginner advice: note that, in many cases using `head, tail, !!, length` in Haskell leads to non-idiomatic code. They are relatively uncommon in Haskell, since they can crash (`head, tail, !!`) or they need to scan the whole list (`length`) leading to inefficient code. The same holds for `last, init`. Feel free to experiment with them, but I'd recommend to learn pattern matching as early as possible, and use that instead when possible. Consider e.g. the snippet `reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]` as a starting point (even if it's not efficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write out a type for your function. A reverse function takes a list and returns a list. So something like

```
reverse2 :: [a] -> [a]
```

Now, let's look at the implementation.

```
reverse2 lst =  if length lst == 1
                then lst !! 0
                else (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
```

Both arms of the `if` need to return a `[a]`, because that's the expected type. The `else` branch is fine; it makes a recursive call, then prepends an element. The result we get is a list. Great! The `then` branch, on the other hand, is problematic. `lst` is a `[a]`, and `(!!)` has type

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

So `lst !! 0` has type `a`, not `[a]`. To return a singleton list, we need to be explicit about it.

```
reverse2 lst =  if length lst == 1
                then [lst !! 0]
                else (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
```

Of course, now this function will fail on the empty list, since taking `last` and `init` of the empty list will fail. So we need a case for the empty list.

```
reverse2 :: [a] -> [a]
reverse2 [] = []
reverse2 lst =  if length lst == 1
                then [lst !! 0]
                else (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
```

And at this point your `null` solution is looking simpler.

Comment: Of course, `lst` is *already* a singleton list, so there's no need to use `(!!)` to extract the value, only to rewrap it. `if length lst == 1 then lst else ...`.

Comment: @chepner That's what I get for writing StackOverflow answers at midnight. Good point xD

Answer (score 2):

You work with `lst !! 0` but this returns an *element* of the list, not a list itself. You thus should wrap the first item in the list, for example with:

```
reverse2 :: [a] -> [a]
reverse2 lst =  if length lst == 1
                then [lst !! 0]
                else (last lst) : (reverse2 (init lst))
```

The time complexity of this is however *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* since determining the `length` of the list, and obtaining the `last` item takes linear time, and we have to do this for all items.

Usually this problem is solved by making use of an *accumulator*: an extra parameter that stores the reversed list thus far and makes recursive calls with a slightly altered accumulator until we reach the end of the list.

In that case we thus implement `reverse` as:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse = go []
    where go rv [] = rv
          go rv (x:xs) = go (x:rv) xs
```

here `rv` is the thus far obtained reverse of the list. For each item in the list, we prepend the reverse list with that item. If the list is thus `[1,4,2,5]`, then we will make recursive calls that look like:

```
reverse [1,4,2,5]
  → go [] [1,4,2,5]
  → go [1] [4,2,5]
  → go [4,1] [2,5]
  → go [2,4,1] [5]
  → go [5,2,4,1] []
  → [1,4,2,5]
```